# LogitModelFit for predicting Categorical Variable

Tags: probability-or-statistics, logic

I was wondering how can I use LogitModelFit to predict the probability of a categorical variable based on non-categorially variables ?

Comment: Can you show (an example of) the data you are dealing with?

Comment: Just replace the two categories of the outcome variable with 0 and 1 and you should be able to throw it into LogitModelFit.